# WebGL – Stretching non power of two textures or adding padding

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm using images of varying sizes and aspect ratios, uploaded through a CMS in Three.js / A-Frame. Of course, these aren't power of two textures. It seems like I have two options for processing them.

The first is to stretch the image, as is done in Three.JS – with the transformation undone when applied to the plane.

The second is to add extra pixels (which aren't displayed) due to custom UVs.

Would one approach be better than the other? Based on image quality, I'd imagine not doing any stretching would be preferred.

EDIT:

For those interested, I couldn't spot a difference between the two approaches. Here's the code for altering the UVs to cut off the unused texture padding:

```
var uvX = 1;
var uvY = 0;

if(this.orientation === 'portrait') {
  uvX = (1.0 / (this.data.textureWidth / this.data.imageWidth));
} else {
  uvY = 1.0 - (this.data.imageHeight / this.data.textureHeight);
}

var uvs = new Float32Array( [
  0, uvY,
  uvX, uvY,
  uvX, 1,
  0, 1
]);
```

EDIT 2:

I hadn't set the texture up properly.
Side by side, the non-stretched (padded) image does look better up close – but not a huge difference:

[Left: Stretched to fit the power of two texture. Right: Non-stretched with padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdKKG.jpg)

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom UV's can be a bit a pain (especially when users can modify the texturing), and padding can break tiling when repeating the texture (unless taken very special care of).

*Just stretch the images (or let Three.js do it for you)*. That's what most engines (like Unity) do anyway. There -might- be a tiny bit of visual degradation if the stretch algorithm and texel sampling do not 100% match, but it will be fine.

The general idea is that if your users -really- cared about sampling quality at that level, they'd carefully handcraft POT textures anyway. Usually, they just want to throw texture images at their models and have them look about right... and they will.

Comment: Fortunately, they're just being applied to a plane – which makes adjusting the UVs easier. From a test of both techniques, I can't discern a different in quality between the two.

I think there's a performance benefit to processing them ahead of time, since three.js is creating a new canvas and applying each image to it in order to generate the texture.

Thanks for your help